# Rails fails to push to Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Any help would be appreciated!

I am trying to push to heroku, but Push rejected, failed to compile:

```
rake aborted!
   Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "   display:none\0/": expected identifier, was ";"
   (in /tmp/build_7fd9b086-bfbb-431a-ac63-9542ddaa4e90/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

I found the display:none\0/ in my style.css file and deleted it completely, but still receive this error. I then did a SHIFT+CMD+F to look for any display:none and all of them seem to be fine.

I also do have:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

in my application.rb btw.

Comment: Did you recommit & push when you deleted the `display:none`?